# How to configure eslint to sort imports using the same way as VSCode's "Organize Imports"?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm working on a TypeScript Next.js project. I want to have the import statements be consistently ordered.

I've tried `eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort` but it seems to disagree with VSCode on the order. For example, this is what VSCode wants:

```js
import { Icons } from '@/components/icons'
import { Tooltip } from '@/components/ui/tooltip'
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useCallback } from 'react'
```

while this is what `eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort` wants:

```js
import { useCallback } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next'

import { Icons } from '@/components/icons'
import { Tooltip } from '@/components/ui/tooltip'
```

If possible I'd like to use the VSCode's default order as that is consistent with all the existing code. But manually running it across all files is very troublesome and I want to automate this. Is it possible to have eslint do this for me, without changing the order and getting huge diffs from existing code?